# Swipelistener not working on menu

Tags: swipe, jqmobi

I am using [jqMobi](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/index.php), ( NOT jQuery Mobile ).
I am trying to get a `swipelistener` to work on the menu.  Basically I just want to 'swipe' the menu open or closed with a horizontal swiping motion.  Here is my js:

```
$.ui.ready(function () {
    . . . . .
    $(window).swipeListener({
        vthreshold: 50,
        hthreshold: 70,
        callBack: function (dir) {                
            if (dir.right) {
                $.ui.toggleSideMenu(true);
            }
            if (dir.left) {
                $.ui.toggleSideMenu(false);
            }

        }
    });
 });
```

This works great except for when I 'swipe' on this red part here -->

[image]

If I swipe anywhere else, it works fine.  I have also tried to use the `document` selector, that also didn't work.  I tried to add another `swipelistener` to the `#menu` and `#menu_scroller` as well.

This is very difficult for me to debug as my device is IOS6 and the "Debug Console" has been removed, so I can't just add a ton of console logging.  ( I don't have a Mac, so I can't hook up the Developer Menu )

My theory is that since there are `ontouchstart` and `ontouchend` listeners on the menu items that this is interfering with my `swipelistener`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swipeListener is being deprecated.  Instead, there are events dispatched by jqUi [swipe,swipeLeft,swipeRight,swipeUp,swipeDown] that you can bind.  The listeners you have for ontouchstart/ontouchend could be killing the event from propegating up though (are they custom listeners?)

```
$.ui.ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("swipeLeft",function(){
         $.ui.toggleSideMenu(false);
    });
    $(document).bind("swipeRight",function(){
         $.ui.toggleSideMenu(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Very nice.  I'll have to better keep up with the latest and greatest.  Also congrats on the Intel deal.